# Check if IGrouping value contains result

Tags: linq, igrouping

I have an IGrouping structure

```
IGrouping<TierRequest,PingtreeNode>
```

PingtreeNode contains a property of Response which in turn has a property Result.

```
    public class PingtreeNode
    {
        public ResponseAdapter Response { get; set;}
        // ... more properties
    }

    public class ResponseAdapter
    {
        public int Result { get; set; }
        // ... more properties
    }
```

What I want to do is check whether PingtreeNode contains any nodes with a Result == 2. I know the answer includes a SelectMany but I'm struggling to get the correct syntax.

Anyone help?

Comment: Do you want the `TierRequest`s that contain at least one `PingtreeNode` with `Result == 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to check

> *whether `PingtreeNode` contains any nodes with a `Result == 2`*

I would use `Any` method:

```
IGrouping<TierRequest,PingtreeNode> source;

bool anyResultIs2 = source.SelectMany(x => x)
                          .Any(x => x.Response.Result == 2);
```

It can also be done without `SelectMany`:

```
bool anyResultId2 = source.Any(g => g.Any(x => x.Response.Result == 2));
```

And because both `SelectMany` and `Any` are lazy (return only one element at the time and end execution as soon as result is determined), performance of both approaches should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, as a result, you want a collection of PingTreeNode that satisfies your condition, this should do the trick:

```
var query = yourstruct.SelectMany(x=>x)
  .Where(x => x.Response.Result == 2);
```